# Obvious defacement of answer approved?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I don’t get it. This proposed edit erased my answer wholesale and substituted a new question, or comment:

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41294245/2

Yet it was approved, and taken seriously enough to be edited further before some kind soul rolled it back? How could that be?

Comment: Probably a mis-click, the reviewer was flying at the usual review speed.  Spent 6 seconds on this one, a minute on the next 6 reviews.  These  kind of robo-click mishaps get worse when it only takes a single reviewer to approve an edit.

Comment: @HansPassant Not a misclick - the reviewer "improved" the Edit suggestion, in other words, _actively_ created some of the changes. Seems that reviewer doesn't understand what they're supposed to do.

Comment: I just wilted a little .. deep inside.

Comment: There are no words...

Comment: By the way, the “kind soul” is https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227743/moritz, who is doing some great work fixing bad edits, and deserves thanks and applause.

Comment: This whole situation can be summarized as: terrible question, poor answer, ridiculous edit. 
**Let's nuke the whole thing and never talk about it again.** Go vote to delete --> https://stackoverflow.com/q/41292565  @matt It should have been obvious that that question was meant to be closed, not answered.

Comment: On a related note I now have a serious beef with the guys who voted to close too broad. The question is narrow enough that there's exactly one way for it to work reliably. Use the accelerometers and GPS to implement a navigation unit.

Comment: @Joshua Well, that's what my answer was getting at.

Comment: On the question of the question itself: I don't think it's a very bad question, and I don't agree with all the downvotes and close votes. I have an app on my phone that detects if I am moving or not, so clearly it is possible. (It is called Pokemon Go, and whenever I am driving I have to click that I am a passenger.)

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy The question doesn't show research effort; so downvotes are justified, IMO.

Comment: @S.L.Barth, Yes, but we should note: downvotes on the question are justified, but the Q&A should not be deleted if there's a good answer. The advice we repeatedly are given is that SO shouldn't lose good answers.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There was only one reviewer. That reviewer [chose "Improve Edit"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20911265), which causes the edit to be instantly Approved with the reviewer's changes.

The reviewer has full edit privileges, so any change they make is instantly applied. The user who made the original edit suggestion gets an Approval in the process.
(Note that it's also possible to single-handedly Reject in this way - if the reviewer had chosen Reject & Edit.)

The reviewer should have Rejected. Instead, the reviewer fixed the capitalization in a textbook bad edit.

For future reference, as the owner of the post you can override these reviews. This is an option available only to the owner of a post, and to diamond users.
In this particular case, the damage has already been undone by the rollback, so it's not necessary to override the review.

Comment: Now that it's on Meta, I expect the reviewer to get a review ban quickly.

Comment: Why was there only one reviewer? I thought the whole point was that it takes multiple approvals to accept an edit proposed by a low rep user. The notice I got said the change was approved by Community. What community? A community of one? This feels like a bug in the design of the review process.

Comment: @matt If a reviewer chooses "Improve Edit", then they add changes to the existing edit. Since the edit now includes changes by a user with full edit privileges (i.e. the reviewer), these changes are applied immediately. And the original suggestion counts as Approved.

Comment: Regarding "Community" - it's attributed to the Community bot. I must admit I'm a little surprised there, I thought it would be attributed to the reviewer. But it's not Approved by "the community" - getting this edit suggestion through, was the work of a single user.

Comment: I don't think a ban is necessary, I'll leave it up to the SO mods, but it wouldn't surprise me if they pointed out this mistake to the reviewer. Now, I have to figure out how or when I'll stop shaking my head, it started as soon as I saw that edit.

Comment: @TimPost I think our reviewers need more training. Just having enough rep to review, is clearly not a good yardstick. At the very least, we should show them the review guidance on MSE before allowing them to review.

Comment: But I'm suggesting the problem is the algorithm used by the review queue. The accept-and-edit _should_ have passed by other eyes in the queue before actually being approved. No one person can be trusted to do this correctly; the example proves it.

Comment: @matt if you disagree that "Improve edit" is equivalent of 2K+ approver making the same edit themselves directly (instead of using shortcut of just posting improved version of someone else edit under they name) - please post separate "feature-request" (or maybe "discussion")… So far it feels like you would like to propose *all* edits to go through reviews by 3+ users.

Comment: @matt some considerations before/for posting your feature request: if "Accept & edit" should still be reviewed, then should "Reject & edit" also be reviewed? Also, if more than 1 reviewers choose either "Accept/Reject & edit", then which edit should be applied to the post? Otherwise, you're basically saying to remove the 2k's "[directly edit posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)" privilege, because they still can edit wrongly, and worse, instantly applied (and it has happened).

Comment: @AndrewT. I see the issue. I guess the simplest suggestion would be to leave the mechanism in place but to opine that 2K proves to be too low a bar for "directly edit posts". Or maybe there needs to be different privilege for working in the review queue, and _that_ should have a higher bar.

Comment: @matt: I'll go one step further and opine that having review be a rep-based privilege was a mistake - especially with the size Stack Overflow already was at the time of its introduction. Stack Overflow needs to accept that people do not just gain the ability to review content the moment they reach a certain rep milestone.

Comment: @BoltClock On sites that are large enough, having the Strunk & White badge might be a good (secondary) requirement.

Comment: @BoltClock - Most of it is inflation. When the original privileges were designed, they were based on percentage metrics and whatnot. However, over time, let's call it 5 and a half years in this instance, getting to 2,000 reputation can be done essentially without any effort or awareness of the overall platform. Perhaps we should instead be looking at requiring some sort of sliding window for reputation privileges (perhaps 18 months).

Comment: My mistake. I only corrected the typo's in the edited answer, but didn't notice the context, where the user deleted the answer and posted a new question. I'm glad it got discovered and reverterd and will definitely spend more attention in the future :(

Comment: @MathiasG., that wasn't a minor error, it wasn't something hard to catch: you entirely skipped reviewing the diff. It's as guilty as failing an audit. I hope you don't do that sort of things for Pull Requests. :)

Comment: @matt: "*Or maybe there needs to be different privilege for working in the review queue, and that should have a higher bar.*" That would change nothing, since a person with "edit anywhere" privileges could have made that change directly from your post. It seems to me that this is an outlier circumstance; it's essentially equivalent to someone with editing privileges making a bad edit. It happens; you deal with it and move on.

Comment: @NicolBolas I disagree on the spirit, though not on the facts. This person would _never_ have directly defaced the post in this way, I'm sure. It's the review queue mechanism that's to blame. The point is that the ability to intervene solo (i.e. Accept & Edit in this case) should not have been granted to this person in the first place. The edit review queue could still be useful if the only things you could do were vote to reject or vote to accept, and if that were all this reviewer could do, the chances of a bad outcome would have dropped sharply.

Comment: @matt: "*It's the review queue mechanism that's to blame.*" No, it's not. It was a simple mistake. If the user had tried to edit your post while an edit was pending review, they'd get the *exact same screen* with the exact same options, that have the exact same behavior. And that behavior is precisely the behavior we want. If I have editing powers, then I should be able to edit the post even if some other user has an edit pending. I would then choose whether to adopt their edits as my own or override it. The user simply made a mistake.

Comment: @NicolBolas Not "simply". The interface shows you the state of the answer before and after the proposed edit. It takes some serious "mistake" foo to miss the fact that the answer has been completely deleted and replaced by a question!

Comment: @S.L.Barth Prior to their being an additional edit, the post author, and moderators, have the option of reversing the review outcome. I don't believe the post author has the ability to "override" an approved or rejected suggested edit once an additional edit has been made (e.g. "Improve Edit" or "Reject and Edit"). The post author has the ability to rollback to the version prior to the edits, as does any user with >2k rep, but I believe that there's no special case for handling a review once someone else has edited the post.